# Is pointing to some elements in a list, restrict the list from being GCed?

Tags: java, list, pointers, garbage-collection

I have two lists

I want to add items from `list2` to `list1`

so that eventually `list1` will be at most with size 4.

i thought to do a simple for loop

```
for (int i=0; i < (4-list1.size()) ; i++)
{
list1.add(list2.get(i)));
}
```

does this `list1.add(list2.get(i)));` means `list1` will always point to elements in `list2`? thus disabling it from being garbage collected?

Comment: _disabling it_ What does that _it_ refer to?

Comment: the list could be garbage collected but not it's elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference to an element in a list will not stop the list itself from being gabage-collected. If there are no other references to `list2` it can be garbage-collected.